# Multiple UITableViews in a UIScrollView like Etsy app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've searched SO a read a bunch threads and haven't found any solid solutions to this.
I'm trying to implement a Controller that displays a "full page" `UITableView` that I can swipe right/left to reveal a neighboring `UITableView`. Essentially I'd like to page through multiple `UITableView`s via horizontal swipe gestures as if they're nested in a `UIScrollView`.

The 2 apps that I see doing this successfully are the new Twitter app & the Etsy app. (12/13/13)

[image: twitter and etsy app screenshots]

I've tried:

- `UITableView`s in a paging enabled `UIScrollView` but the vertical scrolling causes strangeness (Apple warns you that it will).
- I've also tried placing the `UITableView`s in a parent UIView and using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move the UIView around. This seems promising then you don't get the horizontal "snap" behavior you get with a paging enabled `UIScrollView`
- I also tried `PanelTableView` but it didn't behave well in ios7 and allowed diagonal movement etc. It works "OK" on ios6 but the performance is a bit jerky...

I really don't care much about the "..." in the Twitter app's navigation bar or the scroll navigation in the Etsy app. Just focussed on being able to page through multiple UITableViews right now.

Anyone have any suggested strategies to pursue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an easy way to this is by using the UIPageViewController. This way you can add unlimited number of pages, each contain his own UIViewController, or like you want, UITableViewController. best way to that.